# How to Cache Multiple Objects Representing the Same User

Tags: grails, caching, groovy

We have a fairly complicated framework (made up of multiple plugins) that we've developed for all of our future Groovy/Grails applications.  One aspect of this framework is the ability to retrieve user information from the various systems that we store this data in.  Currently we have three classes that represent a user (one for LDAP (non AD), one for AD, and one for database).  The reason for three separate classes is because they access totally disparate systems and are based on different base classes to provide various functionality need to access these systems.  There's also dependencies, etc. that require this three class approach.  One of these classes (the one for AD) is also used by Spring Security to represent a user.  It is also possible to create any user object type from another user object type.

What I'm trying to create is a way for us to cache these objects.  For example, during login, one class is always loaded (by Spring Security).  However, throughout the process of using the application, another class (for database info for example) might get loaded temporarily.  Ideally I'd like to cache these objects (that all represent the same user) so that we don't have to reload information.

In the end what I'm hoping to accomplish, is the ability to pass one user object (say AD) to another user class (say database) factory method, and have the database user class check if it has ever existed before for this user and if so, instead of recreating itself, just grab the cached copy.  I'd rather not use a central cache to do all of this caching, but instead store the cached information in the actual objects (just seems cleaner that way).

What I can't figure out though is how to accomplish this (from a design perspective).  So I'm looking for recommendation on which design patterns might help me to figure out an approach to creating this functionality.

P.S. Just in case it matters, all user classes extend different base classes, however, they all implement a shared interface.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the appropriate caching at the various services that are responsible for looking up the related User instances would be the most appropriate approach. Using the [Cache plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cache) would make this quite trivial.

Your factory method could delegate to the appropriate service method which would be annotated with the correct cache. Just keep in mind that you will need to invalidate items in the cache as well if they are subject to changes.

Comment: Interesting ... can the cache plugin be used with plain groovy classes?

Comment: It can be used with anything. Plain Old Groovy Objects (POGOs), Plain Old Java Objects (POJOs), Strings, Maps, anything you can think of that can be serialized. It's a very flexible plugin.